# VW Polo tdi 1.5 - oil leakage in air pipe reasons

Tags: turbocharger

Oil leakage in pipe between engine and air filter assy .

Answer (score 1):

It’s the PCV system - positive crankcase ventilation.

The engine block has to breathe and, the oil mist is coming through the trap and getting into the air intake - this is normal.